# Differences on generating PNG from XML by gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aapt2

In my project I have xml drawable with gradient and aapt tag

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="361dp"
    android:height="56dp"
    android:viewportWidth="361"
    android:viewportHeight="56">
  <path
      android:pathData="M0.819,0h360v56h-360z">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient 
          android:startY="28.0501"
          android:startX="0.819335"
          android:endY="28.0501"
          android:endX="360.819"
          android:type="linear">
        <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FF724387"/>
        <item android:offset="0.258459" android:color="#FF6D528D"/>
        <item android:offset="0.500962" android:color="#FF6C558D"/>
        <item android:offset="0.741925" android:color="#FF6D528D"/>
        <item android:offset="1" android:color="#FF724387"/>
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="M0.819,0h360v56h-360z">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient 
          android:startY="0"
          android:startX="180.819"
          android:endY="56"
          android:endX="180.819"
          android:type="linear">
        <item android:offset="0" android:color="#28734488"/>
        <item android:offset="0.314917" android:color="#00734488"/>
        <item android:offset="1" android:color="#287569A5"/>
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="M0.819,0h360v56h-360z">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient 
          android:gradientRadius="11.9737"
          android:centerX="180.819"
          android:centerY="56"
          android:type="radial">
        <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FF676395"/>
        <item android:offset="1" android:color="#006C558D"/>
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
  </path>
  <path
      android:pathData="M0.819,0h360v56h-360z">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
      <gradient 
          android:gradientRadius="10.3158"
          android:centerX="180.819"
          android:centerY="0"
          android:type="radial">
        <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FF6D4B8A"/>
        <item android:offset="1" android:color="#006D4B8A"/>
      </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
  </path>
</vector>
```

When I use com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 and gradle-4.10.3-all, in builded APK this drawable put as PNG resource. But if I update plugin to 3.6.3 version and gradle to 5.6.4-all, in builded APK this drawable put as XML. And as result in devices before API 24 I have crashes. How can I fix it without changing XML and separating on drawable and drawable-vXX folders? Why gradle don't generate PNG from XML now?
Maybe it depends on AAPT and changes between different versions of Gradle, but I am not sure.
**UPDATE**
Attach stack trace of error:

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/vd_bg_button.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080280
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2479)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.updateLayerFromTypedArray(LayerDrawable.java:236)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:193)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:145)
        at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.infl
```

Comment: `And as result in devices before API 24 I have crashes` show error log

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya, Update question with stacktrace